# Questions about a natural map: $f^{-1}f_{*}\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits, pullback

By definition
$$f^{-1}f_{*}\mathcal{F}(U)=\lim_{\substack{\rightarrow\\V \supseteq f(U)}} \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(V)).$$

If $V \supseteq f(U)$, then $U \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf, we have the restriction map: 
$$\operatorname{res}_{f^{-1}(V), U}:\ \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(V)) \to \mathcal{F}(U).$$ 
My question is how could we obtain a natural map from  $f^{-1}f_{*}\mathcal{F}(U)$ to $\mathcal{F}(U)$ by using the restriction maps? Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens to the restriction maps when $V_1 \supset V_2 \supset f(U)$? Now just use the universal property of $\lim$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Prahlad Vaidyanathan's comment:

Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf, for all open $W\supseteq V$ we have the restriction map
$$\operatorname{res}_{f^{-1}(W),U}:\ \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(W))\ \longrightarrow\ \mathcal{F}(U),$$
and since $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf, for all open $W_1\supseteq W_2\supseteq V$
$$\operatorname{res}_{f^{-1}(W_1),U}=\operatorname{res}_{f^{-1}(W_2),U}\circ\operatorname{res}_{f^{-1}(W_1),f^{-1}(W_2)}.$$
By the [universal property of the direct limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Direct_limit_over_a_direct_system_in_a_category), there exists a *unique* map
$$\psi:\ \lim_{V\supseteq  f(U)}\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(V))\ \longrightarrow\ \mathcal{F}(U),$$
such that $\operatorname{res}_{f^{-1}(W),U}=\psi\circ\varphi_W$ for all open $W\supseteq U$, where 
$$\varphi_W:\ \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(W))\ \longrightarrow\ \lim_{V\supseteq  f(U)}\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(V)),$$
is the canonical map.

Comment: ... a unique map ... *such that* ... commute.

Comment: Fixed that, thank you.